# QStringList alternative in STL or Boost

Tags: c++, string, boost, stl

Is there any alternative to QStringList in Boost or STL. What I want to achieve is to split path eg. dvb://1.2.3.4/launchpad/dyn/index.htm to separate strings as it can by done simply in QString List:

```
QStringList path = objectPath.split(QChar('/'), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boost::split`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3240174) can split a string into a `std::vector<std::string>`, based on one or multiple delimiters:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> path_parts;
std::string s("some/file/path");
boost::split(path_parts, s, boost::is_any_of("/"));
```